# Bootstrap one button select all other buttons

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

My goal: I want to select one select button when i click him he will need to select all other buttons.

[image: Example to understand.]

So when i select book1 i want it to select 1,2,3,4,5 under it.

Basically i need to group all of this buttons under one button that have the ability to toggle them.
Code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./SelectMasekhtot.css";

const SelectMasekhtot = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("http://localhost:5000/user/getSelectBoxes/");
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='containerSelectMasekhtot'>
      <h1>selection part</h1>
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div className='bookContainer '>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            class='btn-check'
            id={key}
            autocomplete='off'
          />
          <label class='btn btn-outline-primary' for={key}>
            {key}
          </label>
          <br />
          {value.map((arrValue) => (
            <div className='bookChild d-inline'>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                class='btn-check'
                id={key + arrValue}
                autocomplete='off'
              />
              <label class='btn btn-outline-primary' for={key + arrValue}>
                {arrValue}
              </label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default SelectMasekhtot;
```

Explanation of code i have an object that's look like this.
And with him its creating the buttons.

```js
{
//   book1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
//   book2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
//   book3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
//   book4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
// };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "class" to "className" in the return block.

Comment: Done but that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can we try adding an object in state "selected". Let's say it holds values of each key in the data object

selected : {book1: false, book2:false, book3:false}

and then we have to 2 things

1. toggle value on click of button state.selected[key] = ! state.selected[key]
2. assign state.selected[key] for input tags in value.map

Hope it works. I can give a working solution if you can give me reproduceable link

Comment: Is it possible to get something to contact you in private if you have time?

Comment: you can use jsbin(https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output) to replicate your scenario and give data directly instead of axios calls